# Python Class with a lot of arguments

Tags: python, class, oop

I am writing a program for my Vocabulary Trainer.
Therefor I want to create a class for one entry.

But the class will get a lot of arguments, currently around 15.
Is a Class really the right approach then?

```
class Voc_Entry:
def __init__(self, id_n, german, kanji_writing, kana_writing, word_type =  None, date_added = datatime.today(), kanji_write_progress = None, kanji_read_progress = None, kana_read_progress = None, kana_write_progress = None, kanji_write_last_date = None, kanji_read_last_date = None, kana_read_last_date = None, kana_write_last_date = None, kanji_write_next_date = None, kanji_read_next_date = None, kana_read_next_date = None, kana_write_next_date = None):
    self.id_n = id_n
    self.german = german
    self.kanji_writing = kanji_writing
    self.kana_writing = kana_writing
    self.word_type = word_type
    self.datetime = date_added
    .........
```

Or should I make divide that up into functions in the class to get the dates all afterwards?
Thank you for your advice
Styx1337

Comment: what about `*args`, `**kwargs`?

Comment: Maybe it would make sense to group some of these attributes together into smaller classes or NamedTuples?

Comment: It is hard to tell which approach is better without knowing the functionality.

Comment: "@Alexander Lekontsev" is totally right...i would use *args,**kwargs signature here if you want to keep your class as it is. But i would certainly think about splitting this huge class to some childrens classes with inheritance....

Comment: "Is a class really the right approach" - class design depends on more than what's presented here. There is nothing wrong with a large argument list per se. But maybe it makes sense to separate parts, for instance reader / writer / trainer classes, if they have logically separate tasks and you can do some mix and matching. Alternately, using `configparser` and an external file if you want a different way for users to input data.

Comment: @AlexanderLekontsev - **kwargs seems only to reduce typing in this case and ignores the desire for default arguments. The downside is that python no longer checks for required paramters. You have to deal with unwanted parameters and defaults... so more typing again.

Comment: `*args` and `**kwargs` would be definitely the last resort for me, because good luck remembering all the 120 arguments you need to pass there, and IDE autocomplete won't help either.

Comment: Thank you for all the advice.
So to give more background to the program:
I want to create a Vocabulary Trainer for my Japanese Vocabulary, since my Excel solution is not good.

The class should represent one vocabulary entry. I can't use a dictionary, since there are some vocabulary with the same writing but different meanings/pronunciation. In Kanji as well as in Kana.
So I was thinking about creating a class for each entry.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice is to find ways to group the arguments into logical units.  Seeing more of the context would make it easier to make concrete suggestions, but the `kana...` and `kanji...` groupings suggest that maybe there should be some sort of class to represent progress tracking?

```
from datetime import datetime
from typing import NamedTuple, Optional


class ProgressEntry(NamedTuple):
    read_progress: float
    write_progress: float
    read_last_date: datetime
    write_last_date: datetime
    read_next_date: datetime
    write_next_date: datetime


class VocabEntry:
    def __init__(
        self, 
        id_n, 
        german, 
        kanji_writing, 
        kana_writing, 
        word_type =  None, 
        date_added = datetime.today(), 
        kana_progress: Optional[ProgressEntry] = None,
        kanji_progress: Optional[ProgressEntry] = None, 
    ):
        self.id_n = id_n
        self.german = german
        self.kanji_writing = kanji_writing
        self.kana_writing = kana_writing
        self.word_type = word_type
        self.datetime = date_added
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Will check if that works out and try to group some entries into sub classes.